# Is there a name for this linear time and linear space sort?

Tags: sorting

Let's assume we have a data structure called an 'ordered map' where hashing is still a constant time operation but storage is ordered specially for integers from 1 to whatever value is passed in.

```
linear_sort(arr):
    largest_element_in_arr = max(arr) 

    ordered_map = new map()

    // populate values in the map of integers, ranging from 1 to largest integer in array, with 0s.
    from 1 to largest_element:
        ordered_map[index] = 0

    for element in arr:
        ordered_map[element] += 1

    // collapse empty elements
    for element in ordered_map:
        delete if element's value is 0 

    output elements of ordered_map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), except that instead of the normal approach of normalising your domain of values into a range `[0..n]` and counting in an array, you use your hash function to map them to their counts.

It would be useful for sparse data where the input values aren't in a limited range (which is the weakness of counting sort), but of course it does rely on that magical "ordered hash function".

Edit: Actually, given how you initially populate your map, it looks like it's still using `O(n)` space where `n` is the min-max range of values in the input, which means it's exactly equivalent to counting sort - you don't actually use any hash function (your hash function is the identity function, and the special order is the ordering of the natural numbers)!